# Form input old value in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have a search form input where i want to display the searchterm value in the searchbox after searching on the results page.

I tried the following which is not working

```
<input type="text" name="search" value="{{ old('search') }}" placeholder="Search help articles" class="form-control form-control-gray col-md-10">
```

What is incorrect in the value=""

Comment: Is the form method POST or GET.

Comment: Why not just use `request('search')`?   old is when the data is flashed to the session, usually for redirects.

Comment: Form is get method as its a search form.

Comment: @Devon you mean instead of {{ old('search') }} use {{ request('search') }} in the value?

Comment: @Devon that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`old()` is used when flashing data to the session.  This is mostly used for forms which involve redirects back when something fails.  Read about [old input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#old-input) here.

`request()` should be used here since you're wanting to display the value that was submitted on that request.